# How do I set the session cookie path in cakePHP while still saving session data in the database?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, session-cookies

By default cakePHP puts the session cookie at the application level. For instance, if you have a cakePHP application at www.mydomain.com/myapp the cookie is stored at "/myapp".
I need my session data available to other applications at www.mydomain.com, so I would like to have the session cookie stored at "/" instead.

I found a bunch of articles on how to do this, but when using the methods explained in both of these popular posts/guides, it disables sessions being saved in the database.

[How to bend CakePHP's session handling to your needs](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/admad/2009/09/02/how-to-bend-cakephp-s-session-handling-to-your-needs)

[cakePHP - Cookbook - Sessions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions)

Does anyone know how to change the session cookie path to "/" while still being able to save session data in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: And just to clarify, cakePHP can already save session data in the database. However, when it does this (by default) it sets the session cookie path at the app directory level, which isn't what I want. I want it at the web root level.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input, but unfortunately I wasn't able to get the answer I was looking for. At this point in time I have made a small one line change in the core cake_session.php file that fixes this problem. It is totally a hack and I hate that I had to do it that way, but it works. If anyone sees a way to do this without re-writing cakePHP code and without hacking it's core files, I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Can this not be done at the PHP level rather than in CakePHP itself?

So you can use [`session_set_save_handler()` (man page)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) in the following sort of way to achieve sessions stored in the database. The following code is from a comment on the PHP [manual page by maria at junkies dot jp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#79706) and I have not specifically tested it:

```
<?php
class Session
{

    /**
     * a database connection resource
     * @var resource
     */
    private $_sess_db;

    /**
     * Open the session
     * @return bool
     */
    public function open() {

        if ($this->_sess_db = mysql_connect(SESSION_DB_HOST,
                                            SESSION_DB_USER,
                                            SESSION_DB_PASS)) {
            return mysql_select_db(SESSION_DB_DATABASE, $this->_sess_db);
        }
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Close the session
     * @return bool
     */
    public function close() {

        return mysql_close($this->_sess_db);

    }

    /**
     * Close the session
     * @return bool
     */
    public function close() {

        return mysql_close($this->_sess_db);

    }

    /**
     * Read the session
     * @param int session id
     * @return string string of the sessoin
     */
    public function read($id) {

        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT `data` FROM `sessions` " .
                       "WHERE id = '%s'", $id);
        if ($result = mysql_query($sql, $this->_sess_db)) {
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
                $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                return $record['data'];
            }
        }
        return '';

    }

    /**
     * Write the session
     * @param int session id
     * @param string data of the session
     */
    public function write($id, $data) {

        $sql = sprintf("REPLACE INTO `sessions` VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')",
                       mysql_real_escape_string($id),
                       mysql_real_escape_string($data),
                       mysql_real_escape_string(time()));
        return mysql_query($sql, $this->_sess_db);

    }

    /**
     * Destoroy the session
     * @param int session id
     * @return bool
     */
    public function destroy($id) {

        $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `id` = '%s'", $id);
        return mysql_query($sql, $this->_sess_db);

}

    /**
     * Garbage Collector
     * @param int life time (sec.)
     * @return bool
     * @see session.gc_divisor      100
     * @see session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
     * @see session.gc_probability    1
     * @usage execution rate 1/100
     *        (session.gc_probability/session.gc_divisor)
     */
    public function gc($max) {

        $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `timestamp` < '%s'",
                       mysql_real_escape_string(time() - $max));
        return mysql_query($sql, $this->_sess_db);

    }

}

//ini_set('session.gc_probability', 50);
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'user');

$session = new Session();
session_set_save_handler(array($session, 'open'),
                         array($session, 'close'),
                         array($session, 'read'),
                         array($session, 'write'),
                         array($session, 'destroy'),
                         array($session, 'gc'));

// below sample main

session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);

?>
```

So you could reference that in your bootstrap file.

Comment: This is essentially what cakePHP already does, so I was not wanting to rework that. I was just hoping there was a way to override their session.cookie_path ini setting, without hacking their core code, and still saving data in the database. In cakePHP you can set custom session handling in the core config, and I attempted something very similar to what you posted while trying to leverage the functions cakePHP already has in place for all of these functions, with no success. I am still not giving up on this idea, I just don't want to rework functions they already have that work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, sessions in a normal server should be global by default. At least have been in all servers, that I have used.. So I would actually change my server before some hardcore work-around in the script.

However, if you are using some session related class, that has `__destruct()` function at the end..and in it, you have `session_destroy();` OR it doesn't really matter, where the session_destroy(); sits, but it does matter for your path related issue. I ran some quick tests and sessions by default are global within the domain...however, on the second page obviously the variable isn't being displayed, if the trigger page kills it.

My test:

**trigger.php file:**

```
<?

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';

// session_destroy(); <- This kills it
// Otherwise $_SESSION['foo'] gets displayed on the child.php file in test/ directory

?>
```

**test/child.php file:**

```
<?

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['foo'];

?>
```

Comment: I am talking about sessions. My question has nothing to do with the setcookie function. When dealing with sessions in PHP a cookie is saved which holds the session ID, so that when the user moves between pages on your website, it can pull the correct session data.

Comment: Well technically speaking, it sessions should be global over the domain. I have never really payed any attention to it.

Comment: I changed my answer, however I'm not sure if i'm understanding you correct. So correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Session scope is defined in PHP ini and by default is set to global, example config:

`; The path for which the cookie is valid.
session.cookie_path = /`

cakePHP, unfortunately, edits the ini setting using the ini_set function

Comment: Ok, but why are you using that framework? Creating a UI class that uses additional DB class for sql connections is very easy to make.. Cant you edit the cakePHP core, that it wouldn't edit your ini_set functions..?

Comment: We use cakePHP because it provides an easy way to quickly develop web applications. As for editing the cakePHP core, yeah, that is totally possible, but by doing that that makes the cakePHP not as easily upgradable in the future. cakePHP provides many ways to customize it without hacking it's core files. I was hoping for a way to do this without hacking it's core.